# Flatten a nested type hierarchy into a linear sequence of types for std::function

Tags: c++, templates

Consider this (not working) code.

```
template<class A, class B>
struct Param {
  typedef A A_t;
  typedef B B_t;
};


template<class P>
struct FuncType
{
  typedef std::function<void(typename P::A_t, typename P::B_t)> Func_t;
};


void foo(float a, float b,float c)
{
}


int main()
{
  // this doesn't work, as 2nd parameter is nested
  typedef Param< float , Param<float,float> > FloatFloatFloat;

  FuncType<FloatFloatFloat>::Func_t f = foo;

  f( .1 , .2 , .3 );
  
}
```

It works in the simpler, not nested parameter construction:

```
void foo(float a, float b)
{
}


int main()
{    
  typedef Param< float , float > FloatFloat;

  FuncType<FloatFloat>::Func_t f = foo;
```

The idea is to have the `FuncType` class template work on the type `Param` where the template parameters can be either simple built-in C++ types or `Param` itself. In other words: The `std::function` parameter list should contain all built-in types contained in the nested `Param` type.

Is this possible with C++ (can be any standard up to C++20)?

Comment: Almost dupe/closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170425/get-the-flattened-tuple-type-from-an-arbitrarily-nested-tuple-type/68170660

Comment: @Frank If I understand correctly the flattened sequence still got the tuple around it, like tuple<float,float,float>. I experimented with tuple a bit (not what you suggested) but the function<void(tuple<float,float,float>)> wouldn't accept a function of type void(float,float,float). The tuple around it bothers the compiler.

Comment: But it's probably possible to get rid of the tuple with another trait class.

Comment: The more I look at your question, the more I wonder if it might be an X/Y problem. Is the nesting truly needed, or is it there just to avoid having to use variadic templates? [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Tf9vfbofo) would be a lot simpler if it's the later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template<class A, class B>
struct Param {
  typedef A A_t;
  typedef B B_t;
};

template <typename T>
struct FlattenParam {
    using type = std::tuple<T>;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct FlattenParam<Param<A, B>> {
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
        std::declval<typename FlattenParam<A>::type>(),
        std::declval<typename FlattenParam<B>::type>()));
};

template<class P>
struct FuncType
{
  template <typename ...Ts>
  static std::function<void(Ts...)> helper(std::tuple<Ts...>);
  using Func_t = decltype(helper(std::declval<typename FlattenParam<P>::type>()));
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3z3voqqKq)

Comment: I haven't looked at that answer, but the techniques I used are well-known. So it wouldn't surprise me if that answer shows something similar.

Comment: So, in a nutshell you pack the Params into a tuple so you can use tuple_cat to recursively concat them, later you remove the tuple. Very cool.